# Setting PN532 operating mode

Tags: gpio, i2c, spi, nfc

How do you set operating mode of PN532 NFC reader/writer?

[Tutorial on ITEAD PN532](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=78966) states which codes should be used to set system into I2C (`SET0=1 SET1=0`) and SPI (`SET0=0 SET1=1`) mode (default is UART with two `0`s), but I am a noob and cannot find how to actually set them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set0 and Set1 are switches on the ITEAD PN532 card - physical switches indicated on the card itself with the words "SET0" and "SET1". To enable SPI mode, make sure SET0 is set to L (Low) and SET1 is set to H (High) by sliding the white switch to the correct position (marked with L and H respectively).

Comment: Now when I look, there was a photo without any comments :D.